# How to use setOnClickLisenter in Android viewModels?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

**RestActivity**

```
package com.example.internet_ex

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path
import java.lang.StringBuilder

data class Owner(val login: String)
data class Repo(val name: String, val owner: Owner, val url: String)
data class Contributor(val login: String, val contributions: Int)

interface RestApi {
    @GET("users/{user}/repos")
    suspend fun listRepos(@Path("user") user: String): List<Repo>

    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
    suspend fun contributors(
        @Path("owner") owner: String,
        @Path("repo") repo: String
    ): List<Contributor>
}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val baseURL = "https://api.github.com/"
    private lateinit var api: RestApi
    val userName = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val response = MutableLiveData<String>()


    init {
        retrofitInit()
        refreshData()
    }

    fun refreshData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val repos = api.listRepos(userName.toString())
                response.value = StringBuilder().apply {
                    repos.forEach {
                        append(it.name)
                        append(" - ")
                        append(it.owner.login)
                        append("\n")
                    }
                }.toString()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                response.value = "Failed to connect to the server"
            }
        }
    }

    private fun retrofitInit() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())

            .build()

        api = retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java)
    }
}


class RestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rest)

        myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
//        problem
        myViewModel.userName.observe(this) {
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.queryBtn).setOnClickListener {
                myViewModel.userName.value = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nameText).toString()
                myViewModel.refreshData()
            }
        }
        myViewModel.response.observe(this) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textResponse).text = it
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.queryBtn).setOnClickListener {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_rest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textResponse"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/queryBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/queryBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Query"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
**activity_rest.xml**
```

I made a place where I commented that it was a problem because I wanted to change the `userName` in the `ViewModel` when I pressed `queryBtn`, but it didn't work. I want to change the `LiveData (userName)` in the ViewModel using the `setOnClickLisenter` command, but I can't figure it out. And I would appreciate it if you could let me know what to study additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnClickListener` needs to be set outside of the `observer`.
At least from what I can tell you don't need to `observe` `userName` as the `queryBtn` is used to activate a `response`, and **NOT** the fact that `userName` was changed.

But you do want to `observe` the `response` as it is changed in the `ViewModel`, and needs to be displayed in `textResponse`.

The code below is **NOT** checked for correctness I just copied what you had and removed the unnecessary bits.

```
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.queryBtn).setOnClickListener {
          myViewModel.userName.value = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameText).getText().toString()
          myViewModel.refreshData()
    }
    myViewModel.response.observe(this) {
          findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textResponse).text = it
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if you press queryBtn, the program ends.

Comment: Again I copied your code, you have an another error nameText is not a `Button` its an `EditText`. And if you want the text from the `EditText` you call `getText().toString()`  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I changed it as you modified it, but this time the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Move this outside observer block

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.queryBtn).setOnClickListener { 
              myViewModel.userName.value = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameText).getText().toString()
}
```

Inside observer block, when user String is updated, call refresh data

```
myViewModel.userName.observe(this) {
      myViewModel.refreshData()
  }
```

Remove `onClickListener` from `response` observer block.